# How do I change the date format to "dd / mm / yy"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Although I use 'toISOString ()' in javascript, it recorded as in photo 2. How do I change this format.

***Note:*** I am using AngularJs. picture 1 is **list.component.ts**

**Additional files:**

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irxhs.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMFZ7.png)

picture 1:

```js
formatDate(e) {
  var convertDate = new
  Date(e.target.value).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  this.studentForm.get('dob').setValue(convertDate, {
    onlyself: true
  })
}
```

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. As for your question: it implies that you have a `Date` object, and formatting those is a solved problem. And you can always use methods like `getMonth()` to compose the string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `intl` object provided by JS like this -

```
const date = new Date();
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date);
```